# Counting how many times an ID appears within subsequent 180 days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe that includes these columns:

```
REF_ID       REPORT_DATE_RAW
12345      2019-02-21 20:53:00
```

I want to look at each particular `REF_ID` and whether or not it has been reported more than one time within 180 subsequent days from `REPORT_DATE_RAW`. **If it does not appear within 180 subsequent days, it counts as a false positive**. I want to return a 1 if Yes and 0 if No.

I will need to do this for each REF_ID. I attempted to do this with groupby and a rolling sum, referencing another similar question on here. Here is what I have currently:

```
df['REPORT_DATE_RAW'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REPORT_DATE_RAW'])

delta=180
df = df.set_index('REPORT_DATE_RAW').assign(count=1).groupby('REF_ID').rolling(f'{delta}D').sum() - 1
```

This returns:

```
REF_ID   REPORT_DATE_RAW      count
8637    2019-10-25 16:39:00    0.0
8637    2019-10-31 10:38:00    1.0
```

I'm not sure I can do an analysis with these results.... I am not sure why the first occurrence has a count of 0 and the other a count of 1. These two REF_IDs are within 180 days, so I just want to count this REF_ID as 1 so I can figure out how many REF_IDs are considered false positives.

Thanks in advance. This project is very time sensitive so I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```py
(df.set_index('REPORT_DATE_RAW').groupby('REF_ID')
 .apply(lambda x: (x[::-1].rolling('180d').count() > 1)[::-1].astype(int))
)
```

where the `[::-1]` notation makes a forward `rolling` approach.

---

Note: Pandas as a [`pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for forward functions, but it doesn't seem to work with datetime windows.

Comment: Thanks. This changes every column value to 0 or 1 but I can work around that... just out of curiosity do you know of a faster way to do this? My dataset has over 400k rows so the .apply() takes a really long time. Just a rough idea, no need to code it all out

Comment: If you have other columns in your dataset, and you wanna avoid them to be an output for the `count` method, just specify one of the columns after the `groupby`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: About your second issue, though, I don't know how to get around the `apply` because you want a forward count, don't you? I can think in a work-around only if you know all of your days are consecutive (which mean, no gaps) (in this case, we can safely use `shift`). But anyways, notice that `apply` here is applying a rolling approach per unique REF_ID, not per row!